# Переклад словосполуки

Tags: переклад, from-english

Який із двох перекладів словосполуки **to charge royal prices** є правильним, згідно з правилами української мови: *встановити королівські розцінки* чи *стягнути королівську плату*?

> Big job, mind, a place like this. I’ll have to charge royal prices.

**to charge** означає "стягувати, встановлювати, вимагати" (у цьому контексті). Це художній переклад фільму про епоху правління королеви Вікторії в Англії і тому я більше схиляюсь до першого варіанту. Цікава Ваша думка, дякую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значення у запропонованих українських еквівалентів дещо різне:

- «стягнути королівську плату» — це вже виконаний факт оплати (добровільно чи примусово вже змусили когось сплатити);
- «встановити королівські розцінки» — це лише встановлення запропонованої ціни (за такою ціною, може, ніхто й не захоче купувати).

Але що більше пасує оригіналу і чи взагалі ця різниця суттєва в даному контексті — мені важко сказати.

Comment: або не виконаний, а такий, що відбудеться один раз.
"цього разу я муситиму стягнути королівську плату". "цього разу я буду вимушений стягнути королівську плату".